# Android bring activity to front

Tags: java, android

We have a requirement to have our application always be on top.  Effectively we need to create a kiosk mode for the device.  These devices will be supplied to users so they are only using our application on the device.

We have done some research into trapping all possible key events such as the user pressing Home and Search but this method seems quite difficult.

We have decided to try creating a service with our application that will monitor what the topmost process is and if it is not our application to return ours to the top.  We are stuck on the part of bringing our application to the top.  When attempting to use StartActivity(), nothing happens.  We thought it would be possible to do this in the same way that the home launcher calls our activity.

We have reviewed all posts related to this but haven't seen to found the right solution.  If there is a better way to go about it, please let me know!

many, many thanks.

Comment: How nasty! What happens on incoming phone calls? The device can't take phone calls while in kiosk mode? Sounds so hacky that you should consider using a customized ROM instead.

Comment: it won't have a phone plan.  It's a data collection device only.  It doesn't have to completely lock them in, just discourage using the device for other purposes.

Answer (score 2):

> These devices will be supplied to users so they are only using our application on the device.

The only way that will completely work is if you are manufacturing the device yourself.

> We have decided to try creating a service with our application that will monitor what the topmost process is and if it is not our application to return ours to the top. We are stuck on the part of bringing our application to the top. When attempting to use StartActivity(), nothing happens. We thought it would be possible to do this in the same way that the home launcher calls our activity.

Why don't you just make your application the home screen? That way, anyone pressing HOME will go to your application.

Of course, users can reboot these devices into "safe mode" and remove your app, unless you are manufacturing the device yourself and can have yours be the firmware's home screen.

Comment: You technically don't have to manufacture it yourself, but it *will* need a customized ROM.

Comment: @EboMike: True, but I'm assuming/hoping/whatever that the OP isn't going to distribute hardware that is out of any sort of warranty. Maybe they will warrant the equipment themselves or something.

Comment: thanks guys, I would prefer not to go this route for the warranty issue as well as flexibility to move to other hardware.  They really just don't want users to be browsing the web and such.  If they have any technical ability and hack there way out then this is not a concern

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm developing an application which has to be unexitable. This is because this app is used by traffic wardens, not for daily phoning and we had to make sure that they don't exit our app and surf on the internet instead of working.

So you have to put this into your mainfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.droid"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" /> 

    <application 
        persistent="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".YourActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 
    </application>
</manifest>
```

You have to put a boot receiver class in your app:

(BootReceiver.java)

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        Intent startupIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
        startupIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(startupIntent);
    }

}
```

After this you have to disable all buttons in your Activities:

```
/**
 * This method disables all buttons.   
 */
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return true;
}

/**
 * This method disables all buttons.
 */
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return true;
}
```

Now you have the foundation of an application which cannot be exited (even the user presses the home button), and if he restarts the phone your application runs as soon as the boot is completed. Now he can only wipe your app if he has adb (and you left usb debugging on), or if he hard resets the phone.

Feel free to ask questions if it is not clear or if i left some mistakes in the code below. And by the way you have to replace the ...-s in   with your own code.

*Edit: corrected the xml.*

Comment: I will check this tomorrow, to be more precise (now I am at home).

Comment: What about if the user has somebody else call the phone (after acquiring the phone number?) What about holding down the HOME button to switch tasks? What about holding the camera button to switch to the camera app? (Maybe some of those are covered by the onKey* handlers, but I'm not so sure.) What about installing an app via market.android.com (assuming the connected gmail account is known?)

Comment: @edem: With the manifest you have listed here, the HOME button should still work. You would need one of your activities to use the `HOME` category and be configured as the default home screen. And you still have to deal with safe mode restoring access to the device's own home screen, in addition to the holes you note. I'm not quite sure what your boot-time `BroadcastReceiver` is buying you, though there may be something I'm missing there.

Comment: Thanks gents, I can give this method a try.  I just assumed it was going to be too difficult to trap all possible cases.  I know an app called Toddlerlock has succeeded to do this though.

Comment: edem, can you tell me why the need for the 2 activity references in your manifest?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this method is going to be really challenging as I need to permit the user to select the menu and other keys.  Another reason why I was heading down the route of just putting the app back on top was to provide a way for the user to temporarily get out to perform some other require operation such as setting up wifi connection and such but then resuming after X minutes.  Would love it if anyone could tell me why I can launch my activity from within the service

Comment: Corrected the xml error. Our phone numbers are not public and we have google maps appear if the user double-taps the home button...he can't exit from it only touch the home button again to return to our app. If the user taps home button nothing happens. Camera keys are disabled too.